# Laravel 8 component: Undefined Variable when passing value as HTML attribute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I create a new component in my project:

```
php artisan make:component dummy
```

Then in dummy.blade.php I just add:

```
{{-- random quote --}}
<div>
    {{ $title }}
</div>
```

In my view I call the component as:

```
<x-dummy title="Some Title"></x-dummy>
```

It returns the following error:

```
Undefined variable: title (View: .... )
```

Of course, if I change the `{{ $title }}` in the view for a static text, it works fine. If I pass the variable as a x-slot it also works:

```
<x-dummy>
  <x-slot name="title">
    Whatever
  </x-slot>
</x-dummy>
```

In [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components) says I can pass data as HTML attributes

So, what am I doing wrong?

---

**More info**

I was told to delete this post as is non an issue, but I'll leave it here, since it is a reminder that there are two types of components, the ones you create using the `php artisan create:component` and the anonymous.

I was trying to create an anonymous component, but user the other method instead

To create an anonymous component, you simply create a file in `/resources/views/components`, in my case would've been `dummy.blade.php`, with this kind of components you can pass data through the HTML properties like `<x-dummy title="whatever">`

These kind of components are quite useful for things like buttons, forms, and other static things that doesn't depend on going to the database to construct them.

Comment: you need to accept that value and assign to `public $title` in `__construct()` method please read doc  in `dummy.php`

Comment: Has that changed from Laravel 7 to 8?

Comment: just read the doc which you refer in question component create 2 file one is `blade` and on is `php` so in `php` file you need to accept the data and assgin to public then you can use in `blade`

Comment: yes accept that in `__construct($title){ $this->title = $title;}` like this

Comment: Got it... was a typo, thanks!

Comment: delete this post as it is not a issue

Comment: Also, to avoid problems make sure to PascalCase the component's class name. The command should be: php artisan make:component Dummy